# jquery file tree root

Tags: jquery, file, tree, root

hey guys, i just want to ask if the jquery file tree plugin is able to list my folders and files under my "C:/" drive. how can i able to do that? 
i used -> root: 'C:/' but it doesnt seem to be working.

thanks.

Comment: I couldn't think of anything scarier than JS having access to the HDD.

Comment: i just need to do write a web application that could manage your own directories in your own file system. that's all. :)

Comment: as the answers have mentioned, it's impossible for JS to access your file structure. Think about all the possible security issues that could arise from malicious JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery, and javascript in general, does not have access to your file system.

It is more meant for providing a user interface into remote filesystems.  You could however host a web server on your computer, and provide a method of querying your filesystem's structure via HTTP requests which could then be parsed into a file tree object.

Comment: thanks zack.. but is there any way to display a file tree of my file system in my web page? im using jsp and spring mvc but im still quite new.

Comment: For security reasons, it is not possible to get information about the client's filesystem.  Most web servers support some type of file system browsing, or you could use FTP.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function() {

            $('#form_id').fileTree({
              root: '/',
              script: 'jqueryFileTree.php',
              expandSpeed: 1000,
              collapseSpeed: 1000,
              multiFolder: true
            }, function(file) {
                alert(file);
            });         
        });


    </script>
```

and in 'jqueryFileTree.php' write

```
$root = isset($root) ? $root : "";
```

this as the first line of code and then your jquery file tree can access c : drive and show the folder structure.

Comment: This should be the selected as the correct answer.  All the other responders have no idea about the server side component of the jQuery File Tree plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If your connector program is correct,then 
provide with root:'/' which performs structure in C drive.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript hasn't access to your local hard-drive. You doesn't want that for security reasons.

or you need to run ActiveX or something.

EDIT: 
If you use Java, maybe you can use a extension to you webapp:

example:

http://www.webworks.dk/jeexplorer/index.jsp?page=1004&title=Home

Comment: But it still can, right? Can you help me with this? thanks michel